# Copy Text that matches a regular expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio, notepad++

I have a regular expression that has several matches in a textfile.
I want to copy only the the matches to a second file. I dont want to copy the lines that contain the matches: I only want the matched text.

I dont find a way to do this in notepad++ (only copies complete lines, not only the matches). Also not in Visual Studio search.

Is there a way to copy only matches? Maybe in grepp or sed?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your regex?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with both. Lets say I have a following file -

#### Sample file:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat myfile 
this is some random number 424-555
and my cell is 111-222-3333
and 42555 is my zip code
```

And I want to capture **`only numbers`** from **`myfile`**

### Using `sed`:

With `sed` you can use the combination of `-n` and `p` option along with `grouped pattern`.

```
sed -n 's/.[^0-9]*\([0-9-]\+\).*/\1/p'
   |   |          |          |  |  ||
    ---            ----------    -- |
     |                  |        |  ---------> `p` prints only matched output. Since
     V                  V        V              we are suppressing everything with -n
 Suppress       Escaped `(`      \1 prints      we use p to invoke printing.
 output        start the group   first matched   
               you can reference  group
               it with \1. If you
               have more grouped
               pattern then they can
               be called with \2 ...
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed -n 's/.[^0-9]*\([0-9-]\+\).*/\1/p' myfile 
424-555
111-222-3333
42555
```

***You can simply re-direct this to another file.***

### Using `grep`:

You can use either -

```
egrep -o "regex" filename
```

**or**

```
grep -E -o "regex" filename
```

**From the man page:**

```
-E, --extended-regexp
    Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (see below).

-o, --only-matching
    Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] egrep -o "[0-9-]+" myfile
424-555
111-222-3333
42555
```

***You can simply re-direct this to another file.***

#### Note: Obviously these are simple examples but it conveys the point.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(matched text regexp\).*/\1/w matched_text_file' source_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Notepad++ by bookmarking the wanted lines then using menu => **Search** => **Copy styled text** => **Find style (marked)**. The following lines show the method in more detail:

Example text:

```
aposidfupwoebfadbsf-mytext1-ausdfioabq
qoejbgaoudfb -mytext2-asdoufbnqub
foqiuebgf-mytext3- ñqloienbq
alkbnepaofub -mytext4- jafpoebqaf
```

Want to extract all `-mytext?-` words

Create a Regex to find text you want to copy: `-mytext\d+-`

Use the find function (ctlr + f) of Notepad++ and open the "Mark" Tab:
["Bookmark line" option on "Mark" Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGJUT.png)

Enter the regex, activate the option **Bookmark line** and then click on **Mark All** button on the **Mark** Tab.
[Mark all text we need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g8bU.png)

Finally open the **Search** menu and select the option **Copy Styled Text** and then choos the correct color, like this:
[Select all ocurrences of the regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8goK.png)

Then paste it where you need it.

Here an animation of the entire process:
[Entire process Gif animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BxnH.gif)